# Calculating average price of specific products over time

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, query

I'm trying to create a graph that will show the average price of specific products on my site over a period of time. What I'm struggling with is coming up with the most efficient query to use, in order to get the information I need.  I feel that Magento's querying method would be most efficient, so I'd like to know if that's possible first.

What's needed:

- All products and their list price

  - Added **OR** updated in the last 30 days
  - Attribute set ID = `12`
  - Type = `virtual`
- Grouped by option ID from desired attribute ID

Example: `Attribute ID / Code` = `175 / Server`

Options from that Attribute: `Option ID` = `22`, `23`, `24`

I'd like them grouped into the option IDs.

Worth noting: Any item that has the attribute set ID of 12, must have the attribute 175 and one of the options selected.

I then would like to calculate the average of each option ID. So the average of `22` products, `23` products, `24` products, and so on.

I know it seems like a complex query, and I'm unsure of where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to go in a little different direction, but still accomplished what I was initially trying to do.

Worth noting: My site is a multi-vendor marketplace, so the products are those listed by different sellers, however the products the same, just slightly different prices.

My objective: Grab and save the average prices of specific products (all held in different arrays) at least once a day and save them to a new table in order to use them for comparisons/future graphs/charts.

One obstacle: I ran into a problem with special prices, as some sellers were using special prices, while others were using normal pricing.  So if a seller had a special price set at the time of the cron, I wanted to use that instead of the normal price.

My query for calculating the averages:

```
<?php 
    $array = array(11522, 9087, 10689, 7568, 12827, 3593, 2455, 12189); 
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $products = $resource->getTableName('vendor_products');
    $entityTable = $resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_int');

    $query1 = "SELECT AVG(price) 
          FROM (SELECT IF(c.`special_price` = '0', c.`price`, c.`special_price`) AS price 
          FROM `vendor_products` AS c 
          INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS e ON c.`product_id` = e.`entity_id` 
          WHERE e.value = 1 AND e.`attribute_id` = 96 AND e.entity_id IN (" . implode(',',$array) . ")) AS T";

    $avg1 = $readConnection->fetchOne($query1);

?>
```

Explanation: I'm calculating the average, using the normal `price` column in the product table if the `special_price` column is set to `0` (no special price set). The array holds the specific product ID's I want averaged for this specific set of products.  I have 7 queries exactly as the one above, all using a different array of product ID's.  I have these queries set up in a script that runs once a day, and then saves each `$avgX` into a new table I set up to hold each average and the date it was added. So now, when I want to display these averages over a period of time, I can just pull them from the new table, along with the date those averages coincide with.

I took a different route than the original, because I decided not to use ALL items listed since the average could be easily manipulated by a seller who decided to list his item for 2-3 times what its actually worth. So I decided to pick specific items from several trusted sellers.